# Clojure - how to disable logging temporarily?

Tags: logging, clojure

Using `tools.logging` in Clojure, I need to disable logging temporarily while running a particular function, in order to reduce log file sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked on Slack and got almost immediate answer from the creator of tools.logging. The following code binds the logger factory to a default disabled factory.

```
(binding [clojure.tools.logging/*logger-factory*
          clojure.tools.logging.impl/disabled-logger-factory]
  (do-stuff-that-will-not-be-logged))
```